# How to use onUrlChanged?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to log in into gmail account using javascript, and I have a problem:
after I insert my email and press 'next', the page redirect me to new url asking for my password. my question is, How can I monitor the current url and know when it changes? Im trying to use page.onUrlChanged but it doesn't work

```
test.open(url, function(status) {
test.page.evaluate(function (email, password) {
    document.getElementById('Email').value = email;
    document.getElementById('next').click();
    test.page.onUrlChanged = function(targetUrl) {
        console.log(targetUrl);
    }
}, email, password);});
```

Comment: afaik there is no `onUrlChanged` event in vanilla js. are you using some library?

Comment: I am using phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

you can use phatomjs for log URL change..below is simple code for that

```
 var webPage = require('webpage');
 var page = webPage.create();

 page.onUrlChanged = function(targetUrl) {
       console.log('New URL: ' + targetUrl);
 };
```

find more about phantomjs

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-url-changed.html

or

You can use

```
 window.onblur = function() { console.log('blur'); }
```

Comment: I used onUrlChanged, but when I run my code, it stops when it gets to this line

Comment: can you try with window.onblur??

Comment: It is also doesn't run. It just stops

Comment: please add proper html & js file in fiddler